# How to put a space between two SQL columns after joining them?

Tags: sql, syntax

I have joined two columns, first name\last name into one and named it with an alias which is all good. But how do I put a space between first and last name?

```
au.first_name || au.last_name Name
```

Comment: This Question Shows you have not done few research for your solution.

Answer (score 6):

here:

```
au.first_name || ' ' || au.last_name Name
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the space in the same manner that you have concatenated the first and last names,

```
au.first_name ||' ' || au_last_name name
```

Answer (score 2):

if your working on sql server
try the below 2

```
select au.first_name+ '  '+ au.last_name as Name from yourtablename
```

but in this case if you have null values in either of the columns then none of the records will be shown, instead Null will be shown.

or use

```
select concat(au.first_name, '  ', au.last_name) as Name from yourtablename-
```

unlike +, concat will replace null with an empty string. so atleast one name will be shown.

hope this helps such queries being googled

Answer (score -3):

--Combining the Client Address in one column and have comma separating the value.

```
(SELECT (Client.STREET+','+Client.CITY+','+Client.STATE+','+Client.ZIP))AS ClientAddress,
```